# I get 404 error after configuring AspNetCoreRateLimit library in my code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, rate-limiting

When I remove the rate related codes, the app works fine. If I write these codes, I get 404 error.

If `await webHost.RunAsync();` , `await IpPolicy.SeedAsync();` If I remove the await keyword in the , I get the error localhost refused to connect. How can I solve this problem?

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext(builder);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Program>();
builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation().AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters();
builder.Services.AddMapster();
builder.Services.AddIdentity();
builder.Services.AddCookieConfiguration();

builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
builder.Services.Configure<IpRateLimitOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("IpRateLimiting"));
builder.Services.Configure<IpRateLimitPolicies>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("IpRateLimitPolicies"));
builder.Services.AddInMemoryRateLimiting();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IIpPolicyStore, MemoryCacheIpPolicyStore>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitCounterStore, MemoryCacheRateLimitCounterStore>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitConfiguration, RateLimitConfiguration>();

using IHost webHost = builder.Build();
using (var scope = webHost.Services.CreateScope())
{
    IIpPolicyStore IpPolicy = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IIpPolicyStore>();
    await IpPolicy.SeedAsync();
}
await webHost.RunAsync();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseIpRateLimiting();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
RoleSeed.Seed(app);
app.Run();
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": { "SqlCon": "" },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "IpRateLimiting": {
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": true,
    "StackBlockedRequests": false,
    "HttpStatusCode": 429,
    //"IpWhitelist": [ "127.0.0.12" ],
    //"EndpointWhitelist": [ "*:/api/customers" ],
    "GeneralRules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "*",
        "Period": "10 s",
        "Limit": 20
      }
    ]
  },
  "IpRateLimitPolicies": {
    "IpRules": [
      {
        "Ip": "*",
        "Rules": [
          {
            "Endpoint": "*",
            "Period": "10m",
            "Limit": 150
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

i changed the service order and then i got this error how can i solve it?

[image]

Comment: you don't need `await webHost.RunAsync();`

Comment: If I do your said, I take error 'Unable to connect to web server 'ProjectName'. The web server is no longer running.'